# MongoDB - Read array objects and return only the matching objects

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I want to write a mongodb query that allows me to fetch array objects fields based on the IN/OR condition like in relational databases. If I have the following document in my collection, I want to read all "events.event" in ('user','bot')

```
{_id: 1,
sender_id:100,
"events" : [
            {
                    "event" : "action",
                    "timestamp" : 1619463803.7244627,
                    "name" : "abc1"
            },
 {
                    "event" : "user",
                    "timestamp" : 1619463803.7244627,
                    "name" : "abc2"
            },
 {
                    "event" : "bot",
                    "timestamp" : 1619463803.7244627,
                    "name" : "abc3"
            }

}
```

I used the following query but it only works for ONE event at a time. Can this be modified to
consider `event = 'user'` or `event = 'bot'` ? And can we also project `events.event` and `events.timestamp`
along with this `elemMatch`; all in one go?

```
db.conversations.find(
{"events.event": "bot"}, 
{_id: 0, sender_id:1, events: {$elemMatch: {event: "bot"}}});
```

Comment: no, that returns all the array objects and not just the one with event= bot

Comment: You can use the `$filter` aggregation expression operator in your projection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have lots of options

the simplest one that simulates what you have in mind about `SQL queries` with `IN` operator

```
db.putCollectionNameHere.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: 1 } },
  { $unwind: '$events' },
  { $match: { 'events.event': { $in: ['user', 'bot'] } } },
]);
```

about [$unwind documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) says

> $unwind
>
> Deconstructs an array field from the input documents to output a
> document for each element. Each output document is the input document
> with the value of the array field replaced by the element.

Comment: Thank you! I tried the above query step-by-step on MongoDB Compass aggregation pipeline and it worked.